# sed positional replacement with regular expression

Tags: shell, sed

I have string like

```
SELECT dateAdd(dd,-90, MAX(col_name)) FROM table_123_name
```

and I want the output as

```
SELECT MAX(col_name) -90 from table_123_name
```

I have tried with

```
cat test.txt|sed "s/dateadd(dd,//I g"|sed 's/\(\[select\]\)\([ \s\t]*\)\([0-9-]*\)\(\[,\]\)\([ \s\t]*\)\([A-Za-z0-9(_]*[)]*\)/SELECT \6)\3/I g'
```

but regular expression replace is not working

Comment: this is a 'simple' select but are there other select not to take into account or that have nearly same structure like another field selected and should also take into account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
$ echo 'SELECT dateAdd(dd,-90, MAX(col_name)) FROM table_123_name' | sed 's/dateadd(dd,\([^,]*\), *\([^) ]*)\)) *\(.*\)/\2 \1 \L\3/gi'
SELECT MAX(col_name) -90 from table_123_name
```

`i` modifier at the last helps to do a case-insensitive match and `\L\3` turns all the chars present inside the third capturing group to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with `awk`:

```
awk '/dateAdd/ {split($2,a,",");print $1,$3,a[2],tolower($4),$5}' file
SELECT MAX(col_name)) -90 from table_123_name
```

If you need other criteria to search from than `/dateAdd/`, then just change it to what you need.